# How to return value from addEventListener and use it out

Tags: javascript, scope, dom-events

When I want to access to variable `det` out of `addEventListener` I get  undefined.

```
ElementInfo = function(element) {
  var myVar;
  this.tagName = element.tagName;
  document.addEventListener('Mylistener', function(e) {
    myVar = e.detail.workspaceName;
  });
  this.injected = myVar;
}
```

How can I get the value of `myVar` out of `addEventListener`? I don't use JQuery.

Comment: `myVar` will only be populated when the event occurs.  `this.injected = myVar` happens straight away.

Comment: there is no solution for my question is not the same of the question already answer here [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?]